# Классы: одноименные статический и не статический метод

Tags: javascript

Есть ли какие-то подводные камни при объявлении статического и не статического метода с одним именем? Работает ли во всех современных браузерах? Вообще, так допустимо делать? Смотрите пример:

```
class User {
    constructor() {
        this.name = "Name";
        this.surname = "Surname";
    }

    fi() {
        return "this: " + [this.name, this.surname].join(" ");
    }

    static fi(user) {
        return "static: " + [user.name, user.surname].join(" ");
    }
}

user = new User;
console.log(user.fi());
console.log(User.fi(user));
```

```
this: Name Surname
static: Name Surname
```

Comment: Не знаю о браузерах и камнях, но лучше так не делать, даже если сейчас это возможно. Ни в одном языке программирования так делать нельзя. А если и можно задать такое же имя, то сигнатура там всегда другая.

Comment: так можно делать, конфликтов не будет ( если только с коллегам ), статические и обычные методы записываются немного в разные "места"

Comment: @ThisMan меня лично смущает то, что через полгода, когда код подзабудется, в голове будет вопрос - а вот тут вызывается `fi` статически или нет? Придется немножко включить голову, чтобы это понять. Но на данный момент это выглядит удобно. Стоит ли это использовать как фишку? Или лучше разнести на два разных имени?

Comment: по идее видно, какой метод вызывается) Если метод вызывается в контексте класса - статический, в контексте экземпляра - обычный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно вас вводит в заблуждение зарезервированное слово `static`. В javascript оно никак не влияет на то, получится ли статический метод или нет. Собственно в javascript в принципе отсутствует разделение на статические и нестатические методы. Да и сами методы никак не отличаются от функций. Любая функция может быть вызвана как в контексте объекта - с передачей параметра `this` либо без него (то бишь когда this === undefined).

В вашем примере в первом случае функция вызывается в контексте объекта, на который ссылается `user`. А вторая - в контексте объекта `User`. Но это можно обойти используя call / apply:

```
class User {
    constructor() {
        this.name = "Name";
        this.surname = "Surname";
    }

    fi() {
        if (this === undefined)
        {
          return "this: " + "undefined";
        }
        else
        {
          return "this: " + [this.name, this.surname].join(" ");
        }
    }

    static fi(user) {
        if (this === undefined)
        {
          return "static: " + "undefined" + " | " + [user.name, user.surname].join(" ");
        }
        else
        {
          return "static: " + this.toString() + " | " + [user.name, user.surname].join(" ");
        }
    }
}

user = new User;
console.log(user.fi());
console.log(user.fi.call(undefined));
console.log(User.fi(user));
console.log(User.fi.call(undefined, user));
```

Comment: Кажется я начал понимать... Подскажите, если я своем коде начну довольно активно использовать `user.fi()` () и `User.fi(user)` (user тут - простой объект, полученный из JSON), поймут ли мой код? А если придет сеньор, он может сказать, что так делать не нужно, и код надо переписать? На данный момент проект мой личный, но сильно смущает такая "фишка" языка, потому как в других ЯП такое не делается.

Comment: @TotalPusher В javascript код обычно пишут writeonly, то биш одноразовый, так что поймут или нет - не так уж и важно. По идее так делается во многих языках с динамической типизацией - реальные сигнатуры методов задаются при их вызове в рантайме. Другое дело, что в javascript еще зачем-то напихали лишних ключевых слов, таких как `class`, `constructor`, `static`, при полном отсутствии соответствующих фич языка. Неудивительно, что эффект от использования этих ключевых слов идет в разрез с опытом, полученным в других ЯП и создает сложности.

Answer (score 2):

Теоретически, у них разные места хранения и разные цепочки наследования (см. диаграмму в https://javascript.info/static-properties-methods), так что конфликта не будет, разве что в голове читателя. Всё зависит от ситуации. Если есть опасность путаницы, лучше развести.